# UPDATE failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_PADDING'

Tags: sql, sql-server, set, runtime-error, ansi-sql

I have just received the following error, when running an update statement. I have never seen this before, and come from an Oracle Background, so if any one knows this issue, id appreciate the advice. I will keep researching in the mean time.

> Msg 1934, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 UPDATE failed because the
>   following SET options have incorrect settings:  'ANSI_PADDING'. 
>   Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views  and/or
>   indexes on computed columns  and/or filtered indexes  and/or query
>   notifications  and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index
>   operations.

Comment: What type of object that you are trying to update? Is it part of an indexed view?

Comment: Sorry just a table from what I can tell. I do not know what an indexed view is.

Comment: In Oracle it's called a materialised view. You should probably google indexed view and get some background. You can probably find a script that lists all indexed views if you try hard enough

Comment: well no its just a table. the error message is annoying, as it gives 5 things that could be wrong. Wish MS weren't lazy and could actually tell you what is wrong. This also just started happening out of the blue.

Comment: If you only have five things to check that's great (and we just ruled out indexed views). That's better than not having any idea! On to the next one: Do you have any XML columns or spatial columns? Do you have any filtered indexes or computed columns? I remember when I started with Oracle I totally despised it but once I got the hang of the tools (Toad) I kinda started to like it. If you right click on a table and press design you should be able to ind all of that info out. Or you can used system views to work it out if you prefer.

Answer (score 3):

`set ansi_padding on` in my session fixed this. Unsure why this has turned off.

you can check if it is on or off by running this horrendous query to unravel SS method of storing your session properties

```
DECLARE @options INT
SELECT @options = @@OPTIONS

PRINT @options
IF ( (1 & @options) = 1 ) PRINT 'DISABLE_DEF_CNST_CHK' 
IF ( (2 & @options) = 2 ) PRINT 'IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS' 
IF ( (4 & @options) = 4 ) PRINT 'CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT' 
IF ( (8 & @options) = 8 ) PRINT 'ANSI_WARNINGS' 
IF ( (16 & @options) = 16 ) PRINT 'ANSI_PADDING' 
IF ( (32 & @options) = 32 ) PRINT 'ANSI_NULLS' 
IF ( (64 & @options) = 64 ) PRINT 'ARITHABORT' 
IF ( (128 & @options) = 128 ) PRINT 'ARITHIGNORE'
IF ( (256 & @options) = 256 ) PRINT 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER' 
IF ( (512 & @options) = 512 ) PRINT 'NOCOUNT' 
IF ( (1024 & @options) = 1024 ) PRINT 'ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON' 
IF ( (2048 & @options) = 2048 ) PRINT 'ANSI_NULL_DFLT_OFF' 
IF ( (4096 & @options) = 4096 ) PRINT 'CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL' 
IF ( (8192 & @options) = 8192 ) PRINT 'NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT' 
IF ( (16384 & @options) = 16384 ) PRINT 'XACT_ABORT'
```

Comment: This is less horrendous if it helps you overcome your dislike of anything non Oracle: `select sessionproperty('ANSI_NULLS') ansi_nulls_on, sessionproperty('ARITHABORT') arithabort_on;`

Comment: i actually prefer redshift/postgres but without being biased as I am not, TSQL and Sqlservers data dictionary is terrible in comparison to Oracles PL/SQL and its data dictionary, i can't even believe S/S has no median function. For the record TOAD isn't an oracle product its a 3rd party client tool used to connect to Oracle, and others DBs. I use it for sqlserver as SSMS is well, not that good.

Comment: I know Toad is an external product but IMHO Oracle is difficult to use without it. SQL Developer is improving and I am extremely prejudiced against SQLPUS! Good luck with your endeavors.

Comment: really bizarre the 'script table as ....'  set ansi_padding off and then in mgmt studio it fails with the error message above when you try to create the table.   just setting ansi_padding on like ab Bennet says works.   ansi_padding on has to be set above the create table.

Answer (score 0):

I ran a script generated by SQL Server studio and had the error "INSERT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ANSI_PADDING'"

My solution is to add the keyword "GO" and the script worked.